# PHP Imagick "wand contains no images"

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

When attempting to do a simple conversion from PHP, I receive this error :

> exception 'ImagickException' with
>   message 'wand contains no images
>   `MagickWand-2' @
>   error/magick-image.c/MagickSetImageFilename/10080'

What is MagickWand doing there ?? I did not install it...

Here is my simple code :

```
  $a = "/[...]/test.jpg";
  $im = new Imagick();
  $im->pingImage($a);
  $im->readImage($a);               
  $im->setImageFormat("png");
  $im->writeImage("/[...]/output.png");
```

I checked the chmod of all folders... I suspect an 'incompatibility' between Imagick and ImageMagick?
Here is my install details :
 - ImageMagick 6.6.2-8
 - Imagick 2.3.0
 - Php 5.2.3
 - Ubuntu 7.10

If you have any clue pleeeeease! Thanx

Maz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have tried with other image? And be sure that image are exists?
This message say that your image doesn't exist.

Comment: thanx for the clue it made me try with a gif and it worked... So I knew it was from the jpeg + png library...

Answer (score 1):

Well it came from my ImageMagick configuration - my sys lacked jpeg + png libraries

So basically:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
sudo apt-get install libpng12-dev

// + rerun install of ImageMagick + iMagick
// + restart apache
```